# Javascript not waiting for "then" form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to intercept the submission of a form long enough for me to use a 3rd part library to generate an image of a div. But it doesn't ever wait for the canvas to build.

```
jQuery(window).on('dpo_before_form_submit', function (e, form) {

e.preventDefault();

jQuery('#dpo_base_image').remove();
jQuery('body').append('<div id="dpo_base_image" style="width:2000px;height:2479px;overflow:hidden;"></div>');
window.updateBaseImage();

alert($("#dpo_base_image img").length);

if ($('#dpo_base_image').length) {

    alert("starting image capture");

    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#dpo_base_image'),
        {
            useCORS: true,
            allowTaint: true,
            width: 2000,
            height: 2479
        }
    ).then(canvas => {
        alert("canvas built!");
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'properties[_DataUrl]').attr('value', canvas.toDataURL()).appendTo('form');
        e.currentTarget.submit();
    });

}
else {
    alert("Image div missing!");
}

alert("finished!");

});
```

It alerts me that there are 7 images in the div

It alerts me that "starting image capture"

and just jumps down to "finished!"

it never alerts "canvas built!" or adds the property to the form.

Am I misunderstanding how to wait for a promise?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Yousaf I have added a try/catch around the html2canvas code and commented out the submit. it's doesn't alert me of any error and still submits the form even though the e.currentTarget.submit(); is disabled now :(

Comment: check it with console.log not alert.

Comment: Btw, in your code, the "finished" alert will always pop up before the promise finishes because promises are asynchronous. The surrounding function will run in completion before the promise executes. If JQuery and your browser allows it, you could use `async function (e, form)` and then `const canvas = await html2canvas(<same_code_as_before>)`

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do looks fine to me.  I would do the following:

Just before your call to `html2canvas`, try logging what your selector is finding.

```
const dpoBaseImageEl = querySelector('#dpo_base_image');
console.log(dpoBaseImageEl);

html2canvas(dpoBaseImageEl, ....
```

put a breakpoint at the `console.log` and verify you are getting back the selector you expect.

then, take out all the extra props you are passing in (just for testing purposes) and see if that helps at all.

i'd also try just making it extremely simple and just doing something like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="dpo_base_image">THIS IS A TEST HERE</div>';

html2canvas(document.querySelector('#dpo_base_image')).then(canvas => {
    alert("canvas built!");
});
```

**NOTE That we took out ALL of the other `if` conditions, submissions and console logs.  The goal is to keep it simple...**

as has already been mentioned, `promises` *are* asynchronous - so you should def expect your "canvas built" alert to be behind.

My guess though is either

1. Your selector doesn't work
2. The props you are trying to pass in are either wrong, out of bounds or are getting in the way
3. The image you're hoping to capture is not allowed
4. It captured a blank page and so there is nothing for it to complete with.  (thus adding content to the `div` you are trying to capture)

If the above works, try gradually adding some of your configuration props back in until it breaks.   I'd say then you'll know right away what is causing your issues.